# How to use registerForActivityResult in Flutter's MainActivity?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am trying to use registerForActivityResult to create my own native module in Flutter but I keep getting error saying `Unresolved reference: registerForActivityResult`

Below is my code

```
private val takePicture = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { isSaved ->
        if (isSaved)
        {

        }
    }
```

I tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334772/registerforactivityresult-is-not-working-in-flutter) as well but I get the same error message when I create `PickerMethodChannelHandler` as mentioned in the post

Comment: So does your `MainActivity` extend `FlutterFragmentActivity`?

Comment: yes my MainActivity extend FlutterFragmentActivity

Comment: Can you post your full code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from changing `FlutterActivity` to `FlutterFragmentActivity` I had to add `implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.0'` in build.gradle

Also add `implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.6'` otherwise you will get an error saying `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode`